# Parent phone vs. parent's phone

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Is it correct to say: parent phone?
I just want to describe that the phone belongs to the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "Parent" you mean Mother or father the I believe it has to be "parent's phone". But if you are referring to both like "Mother and Father" then its better to be "Parents' Phone Numbers" or in a rough patch go for "Parents' phones".

Answer (score 1):

A "parent's phone" is a phone belonging to a parent.

"parent phone" would indicate some sort of relationship between two or more phones (although this would be very strange wording).

Answer (score 1):

Since you stated that you just want to describe that the phone belongs to a parent, then "the parent's phone" is correct. Basically, in most cases, adding an apostrophe and an "s" to a noun indicates ownership like "the dog's bowl" or "the man's hat."